# What spells/effects will cause a creature to "willingly move"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, forced-movement

As the title says, I'm looking for spells/effects that will cause creatures to move, like one of the effects from the [Confusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/confusion) spell. This is different than "forced movement" like a push/pull/teleport, in that the creature is using its own movement.

Ideally I could combo this with Booming Blade, so while the [Command](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/command) spell qualifies as making the target move, it won't do so if the command is "directly harmful to it". But whether or not it works with Booming Blade (or Opportunity Attacks), I'm still looking for these kinds of effects.

Comment: Would you like answers to include spells that *might* have their target move willingly? What about spells where the target can choose whether to move or not?

Comment: Are you talking about willing movement, or merely movement that still provokes opportunity attacks? The two things aren't the same.

Comment: @Exempt-Medic - yes please. Like Confusion *might* cause someone to move.

Comment: @V2Blast - I'm asking for effects that will cause someone to move, so I think both.

Comment: @emery.noel: Well, willing movement isn't the same as movement that provokes opportunity attacks, as I said - only a few things (e,g, *booming blade*) are specifically contingent on "willing" movement, whereas opportunity attacks are provoked by a creature moving using its movement, action, or reaction (even unwillingly, as from *dissonant whispers*). So which of these are you actually interested in (EDIT: i.e., asking about in this post)? It can't be "both", because they're two different things... If we know what problem you're trying to solve, it'll help us better answer your question.

Comment: @V2Blast - so, OK, I'm seeing the difference now, but I *can* still be interested in both :). I'm not dedicating myself to only one trick. I'm not really trying to solve a problem, just looking for interesting ways to make other creatures move around (using up their own actions, ideally). If I can proc damage or trigger an OA, then that's just better.

Comment: @emery.noel: Sure, you can be interested in both, but they're entirely different questions (and should thus be asked about separately). KorvinStarmast's answer mostly addresses opportunity attacks, and links to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139940/33569) regarding what counts as "willing movement". Since that Q&A already addresses the definition of "willing" movement, you may want to edit your question to ask specifically what spells/effects result in movement that provokes opportunity attacks... (Though asking for a full list of such effects may be too broad.)

Comment: I just noticed that I had not up voted your question, sorry about that. I think it was a good question (good enough to answer) and I usually up vote any question I answer. Now fixed. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Two spells I have used to trigger opportunity attacks

*fear*
*dissonant whispers*

My warlock or bard, respectively, often casts one of those when one of my party members is in melee and if I am successful (the enemy fails the save DC) then my allies get an opportunity attack.

I have seen *command* used to this effect as you mention when another caster used that in a similar situation.  (Confusion should also work, but I haven't seen it at the table).  You could expect that the *antipathy/sympathy* spell to have similar effects.

From the 2019 Sage Advice Compendium (page 8)

> **Does Polearm Master let me make an opportunity attack against a target
> that is being forced to approach me?**
> A creature doesn’t provoke an opportunity attack if it is moved without the use of its movement, its action, or its reaction. For example, the effect of the *antipathy/sympathy* spell requires the target to use its movement, meaning that it would provoke opportunity attacks when it does so.  Similarly, *dissonant whispers* requires the target to move using its reaction (if available), so that activity also provokes opportunity attacks.  In contrast, a creature that’s pushed by a gust of wind spell does not provoke opportunity attacks.

#### Clerics and Paladins: turning enemies

> A turned creature must spend its turns trying to move as far away from
> you as it can, and it can’t willingly end its move in a space within
> 30 feet of you. It also can’t take reactions.

*Turn undead* uses the foe's movement if they are undead; and against fiends, celestials, fey and elementals if the cleric is of the Arcana domain.

The Ancient Paladin's *Turn the Faithless* does something similar to fey and fiends.

Caveats: I don't self proc the effect, as you suggest. Depending on the version of *booming blade* that you are using (SCAG or Tasha's) there may be an issue with using the warcaster feat's feature to self proc the Opportunity Attack.  When they changed the range to (self) it appears that the OA option using *booming blade* was curtailed, whereas the SCAG version was for normal melee range and worked with *booming blade*.

#### What is willing?

That's [somewhat answered here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139940/22566), and it appears to have no consensus and attracts hair splitting.  Discuss it with your DM/your table and come to a consensus that you all can agree upon.

Comment: Turning, fear (I didn't know it did that, drop and flee!), dissonant whispers, and anti/sympathy are all great answers, thanks! I am pretty sure I wouldn't be able to self-proc, but that's OK. I'm just kind of information-gathering here. Thanks!